# Uml designer 7.0 Loading models error

Tags: eclipse, uml-designer

error log with eclipse oxygen 4.7.0

`An internal error occurred during: "Loading models".
loader constraint violation: when resolving field "IS_DETACHMENT" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the referring class, org/eclipse/sirius/business/internal/session/danalysis/DanglingRefRemovalTrigger, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) for the field's resolved type, com/google/common/base/Predicate, have different Class objects for that type`

But when I change to eclipse neon uml designer is well

Comment: Yes the version 7 does not work with Eclipse Oxygen due to a guava version incompatibility. If you want to use Eclipse Oxygen you have to use UML Designer 8.0 beta which will be released at the end of this week. To test it you can download the nightly version available on the download page.

Comment: Thanks for you reply